# What should be an Optimal value of K in K means Clustering for it to be implemented on ANY Dataset?

Tags: r

Like the Question speaks, I'm making a Visualization tool that is bound to work for any dataset provided. What should be the Optimal K value I should select and How?

Comment: this would be better for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), although it's also probably too broad.  What is the goal of the clustering in the first place?

Comment: There exists no "universal" optimal k value that is optimal for *any* dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can use `Calinski criterion` from vegan package, also your phrasing of question is little debatable. I am hoping this is what you expecting, please comment in case of otherwise.

For example, You can do:

```
n = 100
g = 6 
set.seed(g)
d <- data.frame(
  x = unlist(lapply(1:g, function(i) rnorm(n/g, runif(1)*i^2))), 
  y = unlist(lapply(1:g, function(i) rnorm(n/g, runif(1)*i^2))))

require(vegan)
fit <- cascadeKM(scale(d, center = TRUE,  scale = TRUE), 1, 10, iter = 1000)
plot(fit, sortg = TRUE, grpmts.plot = TRUE)
calinski.best <- as.numeric(which.max(fit$results[2,]))
cat("Calinski criterion optimal number of clusters:", calinski.best, "\n")
```

This would result in value of 5, which means you can use 5 clusters, the algorithm works with the fundamentals on withiness and betweeness of k means clustering. You can also write a manual code basis on that.

From the documentation from [here](http://cc.oulu.fi/~jarioksa/softhelp/vegan/html/cascadeKM.html):

> criterion:    The criterion that will be used to select the best
>   partition. The default value is "calinski", which refers to the
>   Calinski-Harabasz (1974) criterion. The simple structure index ("ssi")
>   is also available. Other indices are available in function clustIndex
>   (package cclust). In our experience, the two indices that work best
>   and are most likely to return their maximum value at or near the
>   optimal number of clusters are "calinski" and "ssi".

**A manual code would look like something as below:**

At the first iteration since there is no SSB( Betweeness of the variance).

```
wss <- (nrow(d)-1)*sum(apply(d,2,var))
#TSS = WSS ##No betweeness at first observation, total variance equal to withness variance, TSS is total sum of squares, WSS is within sum of squress
for (i in 2:15) wss[i] <- sum(kmeans(d,centers=i)$withinss) #from second observation onward, since TSS would remain constant and between sum of squares will increase, correspondingly withiness would decrease.
#Plotting the same using the plot command for 15 iterations.(This is not constant, you have to decide what iterations you can do here.
plot(1:15, wss, type="b", xlab="Number of Clusters",
     ylab="Within groups sum of squares",col="mediumseagreen",pch=12)
```

An output of above can look like this, Here after the point at which the line become constant is the point that you have to pick for optimum cluster size, in this case it is 5 :

[image]